# Understanding comment about correlation

Tags: correlation, cross-correlation

In a paper that I'm supposed to be deep reading the author's make the statement:

> "We performed a cross-correlation test among the four measures composing it and found an average cross-correlation of $r= 0.40$.  The strong cross-correlation scores ... justify our decision to equally weight the four socioeconomic measures."

My understanding is that having features/measures that are highly correlated is not a great thing.  Also if they are highly correlated wouldnt the weighting be meaningless since the measures will tend to move in sync with each other?  So if you weight them equally or totally unequal, or even removed a feature you would end up with a similar response/answer.

Also in this context is cross-correlation and correlation the same thing?  My google search gave me the impression that cross-correlation is specific to signal related data like time-series or audio.

Additional Info:
The four measures are Income, Age, Education, and Rent.  They weighted them equally (sum and divide by 4) to come up with a 'neighborhood index' on how affluent that neighborhood based on census data.  There are two different time windows 2000 and 2015.  They subtract the two neighborhood indexes to get a 'gentrification score' which is a measure of how much the neighborhood has changed socio-economically in those 15 years.

Original paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.05924

Comment: Cross-correlation is a generalization of correlation where a time-lag (or lag in index) may be used.

Comment: You might be interested in the subjects of variance inflation factors and multicollinearity.

Comment: @Galen that makes sense in context.  It is time-lagged data.  Two different time windows.  Defintiely studied those two a bit.  Still struggling to rectify my understanding to their paper.

Comment: I'm not sure I have enough information to help you. Could you add more information about in what sense they were weighting the four socioeconomic measures?

Comment: @Galen Done.  Thanks for trying to help me figure this out.  Im assuming that they are doing it correctly and I'm not understanding something it but theres always the chance that smart people make mistakes.

Comment: I unfortunately do not have time to carefully read enough of the paper to reliably answer, so I hope that someone who does can help you. At a glance they might be calculating cross-correlation between indices that are intended to measure similar things. If two estimators measure something similar, they should be at least associated if not correlated.